# Не работает setColor() в lbgdx на Actor'e(ANDROID)

Tags: android, libgdx, mobile-development

Есть точка:

```
class Dot extends Actor {
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
        batch.draw(dotimg, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}
```

Есть inputlistener

```
class MyInputListener extends InputListener{
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        event.getListenerActor().setSize(200,200);
        event.getListenerActor().setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

setSize() работает, а setColor() нет. Как он работает? Почему он не меняет цвет точки? Или это зависит от текстуры? Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо делать так:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    Color batchColor = batch.getColor();

    final float r = batchColor.r;
    final float g = batchColor.g;
    final float b = batchColor.b;
    final float a = batchColor.a;

    Color dotColor = getColor();

    batch.setColor(dotColor.r, dotColor.g, dotColor.b, dotColor.a * parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(dotimg, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    batch.setColor(r, g, b, a);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать, так, чтобы он закрашивал не квадрат, а кружок? или мне нужно обрезать текстуру от белых(невидимых краёв), чтобы он закрашивал только круг?

Comment: и еще пишу цвет в rgba(217, 46, 46, 1), но точка не разукрашивается,А через Color.BLUE красится

Comment: а все, зависит от формы самой текстуры